# How to fix Javascript error in while controller?

Tags: javascript, jmeter

I'm using While controller in my Jmeter script. I have given following condition in while controller

`${__javaScript(${counter} < 10)}`

Though the condition is working as expected but it throws below error in logs.

```
2019-02-02 15:58:21,315 ERROR o.a.j.f.JavaScript: Error processing Javascript: [${counter} < 10]

javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:1:1 Expected ; but found {
${counter} < 10
 ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 1
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:537) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:524) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.JavaScript.executeWithNashorn(JavaScript.java:142) [ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.JavaScript.execute(JavaScript.java:103) [ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:141) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:116) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty.getStringValue(FunctionProperty.java:101) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.WhileController.getCondition(WhileController.java:124) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.WhileController.endOfLoop(WhileController.java:56) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.WhileController.next(WhileController.java:102) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:219) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:173) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:219) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:173) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:87) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:274) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
```

Anyone has any idea of the reason behind this error? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the case your `${counter}` variable is not defined during the first iteration of your [While loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop), the options are in:

1. Give the `${counter}` variable an initial value using i.e. [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)
2. Check whether the `counter` variable is set using i.e. [__isVarDefined() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__isVarDefined)

However you can kill two birds with one stone by migrating to [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) (which is by the way the [recommended scripting option since](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) [JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)), the condition would be:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('counter') == null || (vars.get('counter') as int) < 10,)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing some more backticks.

```js
var counter = 42,
    __javaScript = v => `got ${v}`;

console.log(`${__javaScript(`${counter}` < 10)}`);
//                          ^          ^
```